# SQL - need a query to search messages by recipient

Tags: sql, schema, messaging

I have a simple message schema where a "thread" ties 2 or more users to a stream of messages. Each message belongs to a single thread. It works just like SMS messages, or Facebook messages.

Given a string (representing a name or partial name of a user), I need a query that will find all threads that match where:

1. the current user (userID) is a member of the thread
2. the name or partial name of a user is also a member of the thread

Here are my tables:

**MessageThreads:**
threadID
lastUpdated

**MessageThreadUsers:**
threadFK
userFK

**Users**
userID
userFirstName
userLastName
userFullName

This query gets all threads that the current user belongs to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT threadFK FROM MessageThreadUsers
WHERE userFK = 'usr_developer'
```

But how would I join each thread with all users in the thread (not including the current user) that match by name or partial name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should show you the other users of all threads that the 'usr_developer' key is part of.

```
    SELECT MT.ThreadId, U.userID, U.userFullName
      FROM MessageThreads MT 

INNER JOIN MessageThreadUsers MTCU on (MTCU.threadFK = MT.threadID)
INNER JOIN Users CU on (MTCU.userFK = CU.userID and CU.userID = 'usr_developer')

INNER JOIN MessageThreadUsers MTU on (MTU.threadFK = MT.threadID)
INNER JOIN Users U on (MTU.userFK = U.userID and U.userID <> 'usr_developer') 

     WHERE U.UserFullName like '%John%' -- Do your filters here
```

This joins against the tables twice, first, we join to the users table to only pull back the set of threads that have a user with the id of 'usr_developer'. Then we join the resulting threads against the users table again, this time where the user id is not usr_developer. Finally we can filter the result set by the name.

Comment: Oops just reread, I am fixing this to include the current user must be a member of the thread.

Comment: There's an error on Line 5: MTC.userFK cannot be bound. What should this be?

Comment: This is looking like it will work. One enhancement I need to make is to get the most recent message and the sender of that message for the thread. I can get the message easily (already done that) by comparing MessageThreads.lastUpdated with Messages.messageDate. But I need to join that with the Users table again... I need to get user who wrote that message (Messages.senderFK). Make sense?

Comment: Great! Also, I would recommend using integers as surrogate keys on the Users and MessageThreads tables, instead of characters. Then your joins will perform better.

Comment: I am using UUIDs for IDs, so they're up to 35 characters. I realize that using ints would be better. I'm currently building a site that needs to support millions of users... do you think I'm really going to need to make that change? I suppose I could migrate the system by creating a bigint ID for all objects that use UUIDs, and then change my queries down the road.

Comment: UUIDs are very large. Even if you have 10M users, you would only have 10M user keys (could be some savings in space there). A UUID is always 16 bytes - many DBMS can store numbers in a compressed format (anywhere from 3-8 bytes).